# How to determine the ESD level?

Tags: protection, circuit-design, esd

I would like to know how we determine the IEC 6100-4-2 level for a product.
There are 4 levels, and I don't know what level take.
It's for an encapsulated system with mechanical ground separate from the electrical ground with ESD protection capacitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running the ESD test you need to pass all levels off the test, up to the highest for your product. It's not just picking a level and saying I'm compliant. The various levels are defined becaude the behaviour off your product can pass with the highest level but fail with a lower one.